# Jenkins automatically add job in gui based on Jenkinsfile in repo

Tags: jenkins, automation, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, cicd

I have my pipelines in one bitbucket repo.

```
├── shared_libs
(...)
├── pipelines
│   ├── group1
│   │   ├── pipelineA
│   │   │   └── Jenkinsfile
│   │   ├── pipelineB
│   │   │   └── Jenkinsfile
│   ├── group2
│   │   ├── pipelineD
│   │   │   └── Jenkinsfile
│   │   ├── pipelineC
│   │   │   └── Jenkinsfile
```

So far I was manually creating jobs in GUI, configuring all parameters, repo, paths to Jenkinsfile. Now I'm having hard time to find a plugin, a way to automate it. Sort of auto-discovery that after setting up repo access. It will create a job based on the Jenkinsfile, put it in a correct place in folder structure, set up all parameters. Kind of like with shared libs. Where I specify repo, path, key. And it's ready to use.

As those pipelines are not just to build and deploy but all sort of admin/cleanup work... I don't want to run them automatically. I just want to automatically add element in GUI once it's pushed to repo/merged to master.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can automate the process. It's difficult to give a complete solution without knowing all the bits and pieces. But here is how you can do this.

You can create a new Jenkins Job which will be triggered by a Webhook from the bitbucket repo. The Webhook request will transmit the latest changed files etc. From the request, you can extract the files that were added or changed. Bsed on this information you can use the following Groovy script to create the new Job and move it to the desired directory.

```
def createJenkinsJob(def jobName, def folderName) {

    echo "Creating the job ${jobName}"
  // Here I'm using a shared library in the pipeline, so I have loaded my shared library here
  // You can simply have the entire pipeline syntax here.
    def jobDSL="@Library('ycr@master') _\n" +
                "Pipeline()"
    def flowDefinition = new org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowDefinition(jobDSL, true)
    def jenkins = Jenkins.instance
    def job = new org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowJob(instance, jobName )
    job.definition = flowDefinition
    job.setConcurrentBuild(false)

    job.save()
    jenkins.reload()
    
    // After creating the Job move the job to a folder
    if (folderName != null && folderName != "") {
        def folder = jenkins.getItemByFullName(folderName)
        Items.move(job, folder)
    }  
}
```

Comment: I'm creating new deployment of Jenkins. Newest available version of Jenkins on kubernetes (gke) from helm. As it's still pretty much in poc state, I'm open for any suggestions. Was looking for a plugin that can solve it, but surprisingly I can't find anything. I'll keep looking but creating a dedicated pipeline triggered by webhook will be a good backup plan.